# hauwei e303 is not detected after machine is wake up from sleep

Tags: suspend, usb-modem, mobile-broadband, huawei

I have `huawei e303` dongle. If I plug it and `boot up` my system, it is working fine. And if I plug it after machine is `booted up` it also works fine, but only for the first. If I unplugged it after above mentioned scenarios or wake up the lap from sleep, `dongle` is not detected. Sometimes by `disabling networks` and `re enabling networks` fix this. But most of the time I have to restart my lap to get it working again. Why is this happening?. Is there a fix for this, plz help me to solve this as `restarting` really annoys me as I have to close all the `apps` and restart them

Comment: I'm also facing this same issue. Have you found any workaround yet?

Comment: @PrahladYeri Not yet :(